# "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00" in EDB loader

Tags: utf-8

I am using EDB loader to load data by using files but getting the below error.

EDB format which i have used:

```
LOAD DATA
 APPEND
 INTO TABLE $table_name
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( $columns_name)
```

Error:

> ```
> Rejected Record Number (line no) for relation (table_name) due to the following error:
> "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00"
> ```

sample file formats:

```
"1234","//acsii100\private\test"
```

Please help to resolve it.

whether it will resolve by adding tab '`\t`' at the end of `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the file in binary mode and print it out byte by byte. I'm guessing that the characters will turn out to be 16 bit with zeroes between them.

The other possibility is that records must be a minimum length. That seems unlikely.